# How to enable ssh access without public/private keys

Tags: ssh, shell

I want to access my server via terminal like this:

```
ssh username@host.com
Password: (enters password)
...
```

I have access to cpanel for this server. There is a section called "SSH access" where I can create public/private keys. I don't know how to use them really and I don't want them currently. I just want to specify my password all the time.

But I don't see such a config option anywhere.. Where do I look? Can I do this with cpanel only or I need some extra access to this server?

If I try to ssh now, server responds like this:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: You'll need to contact the service provider.

Answer (score 2):

Change `PasswordAuthentication no` to `PasswordAuthentication yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart sshd.